# Lazarus/Delphi: UnicodeString in self-allocated record data type causes access violations

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation, lazarus, unicode-string, delphi

I guess, my problem is caused by the concept how UnicodeStrings are implemented, but I cannot solve this problem.

I'm trying to scan a directory tree on disk recursively and build a treeview which should show all files and subfolders. Plus, I want to store additional information for each tree node. The TTreeNode object has only a "Data" property (type Pointer) for this purpose, so I allocate memory manually, store the information and assign the allocated pointer to my data property. Everything seems to work fine unless I include usage of a UnicodeString field within my data record.

So, here is my custom data record definition:

```
type
  TFileInformation = record
    AbsoluteFileName: UnicodeString;
    FileSize: Int64;
    FileAttributes: LongInt;
    CreationTime, ModificationTime: TDateTime;
  end;
```

And here is my code for directory recusion:

```
const NO_ERROR = 0;

procedure ScanDirectory(Folder: UnicodeString; Node: TTreeNode);

var
  Details: Pointer;
  NewNode: TTreeNode;
  SearchAttributes: LongInt;
  SearchMask: UnicodeString;
  SearchRecord: TUnicodeSearchRec;

begin
  if (Folder <> '') and (Folder[Length(Folder)] <> DirectorySeparator) then begin
    Folder += DirectorySeparator;
  end;
  SearchMask := Folder + '*'{$IFDEF WINDOWS} + '.*'{$ENDIF};
  SearchAttributes := faReadOnly or faHidden or faSysFile or faDirectory or faArchive or faSymLink;

  if FindFirst(SearchMask, SearchAttributes, SearchRecord) = NO_ERROR then begin
    repeat
      if ((SearchRecord.Attr and faDirectory) <> faDirectory) or
         ((SearchRecord.Name <> '.') and (SearchRecord.Name <> '..')) then begin
        Details := MemAlloc(SizeOf(TFileInformation));
        //TFileInformation(Details^).AbsoluteFileName := Folder + SearchRecord.Name;
        TFileInformation(Details^).FileAttributes := SearchRecord.Attr;
        TFileInformation(Details^).FileSize := SearchRecord.Size;
        TFileInformation(Details^).CreationTime := SearchRecord.Time;
        //TFileInformation(Details^).ModificationTime := -1;
        if Node = nil then begin
          NewNode := self.trvOrigin.Items.AddNode(nil, nil, ansistring(SearchRecord.Name), Details, naAdd);
        end else begin
          NewNode := self.trvOrigin.Items.AddNode(nil, Node, ansistring(SearchRecord.Name), Details, naAddChild);
        end;

        if (SearchRecord.Attr and (faDirectory or faSymLink)) = faDirectory then begin
          // only recurse folders which are NOT SymLink:
          ScanDirectory(Folder + SearchRecord.Name, NewNode);
        end;
      end;
    until FindNext(SearchRecord) <> NO_ERROR;
  end;
  FindClose(SearchRecord);
end;
```

When I uncomment the line containing `.AbsoluteFileName :=`, I get an Access Violation (SIGSEGV-Exception in Unix).
I'm currently using Lazarus in `objfpc` mode on Debian Linux, but I guess it's the same with Delphi on Windows. The Treeview.Data property value is stored in the "Details" variable in my example code, self.trvOrigin is my treeview control.

Comment: Where is the `MemAlloc` function from? As I remember it is Windows specific function. Can found it only in the `FreeVision`'s `Memory` unit (in addition to the `Windows` unit)...

Comment: I use the Memory unit included in Lazarus.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to simply make a derived class from TTreeNode that would contain additional fields that you require. That way you won't have to worry about assigning and releasing memory for additional information by yourself. The only scenario when using of Data property would be better is when multiple of tree nodes would contain same additional information or if this additional information is maintained separately.

Comment: Yes, class derivation is simpler and better. Thanks for this hint. But at first I wanted to solve this specific issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you allocate the `Details` record, the memory is not defined.

`AbsoluteFileName` is a managed type and must be properly initialized before use.
You need to clear the memory after the allocation:

```
FillChar(Details^, SizeOf(TFileInformation), #0);
```

---

As an alternative, use `New(Details)` in combination with `Dispose(Details)`.
They will correctly initialize/finalize the record.

Note: `Details` must be a typed pointer, `PFileInformation`.

Comment: Thank U, this fixed the issue. I was thinking, I initialize the structure by an assignment of each field - but you are right.

Comment: else use `AllocMem` instead of `MemAlloc`; Delphi has no `MemAlloc` function.

Comment: Why not use the New function? That properly initializes the record, and should be used preferrably, instead of GetMem, AllocMem, etc. Free the same record with Dispose and ensure the pointer is of the right type.

Comment: Yeah, @Rudy - defining type PFileInformation = ^TFileInformation, var Details: PFileInformation and using New() seems to be the best solution, particularly for readability.